# How do you create a KX_PolygonMaterial?

Tags: python, game-engine, materials, opengl

I try to attach a PyOpenGL Shader to an object using the `setCustomMaterial()` command but It raises an error: 'KX_BlenderMaterial' object has no attribute 'setCustomMaterial.
So I need to retrieve the `KX_PolygonMaterial` component of my object instead of the `KX_BlenderMaterial` but the function for getting each one of those is the same

```
obj = bge.logic.GetCurrentController().owner    
mat = obj.meshes[0].materials
```

The [corresponding api page](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bge.types.KX_MeshProxy.html) describes the object `KX_MeshProxy` and its function `materials` saying: "list of KX_BlenderMaterial or KX_PolygonMaterial types"

How can convert the BlenderMaterial to PolygonMaterial ?

This code should return a PolyMaterial yet it still gives me a BlenderMaterial back; ALso I tryed checking "texture face" but it doesn't solve the problem

```
mesh = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner.meshes[0]
poly = mesh.numPolygons
for p in range (poly):
    P = mesh.getPolygon(p)
    PolyMat = P.material
    PolyMat.setCustomMaterial(Material())
```

Comment: In the [current version API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_MeshProxy.html) the return is KX_BlenderMaterial, there is no more KX_PolygonMaterial.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently KX_PolygonMaterial doesn't exist anymore.